# Displaying each element of array on new line

Tags: vb.net

Please consider I am very new with VB.NET when attempting to read and answer my question

I have a textbox that takes in a list of words separated with a comma on the same line. When button is clicked string gets assigned to variable text and I then split it to variable arrayText. 
Then I loop over it and display each element of array on new line.

My code looks as follows

```
 Dim text As String
 Dim arrayText() As String

    text = TextBox1.Text
    arrayText = text.Split(",") 'every "," generates new array index, removes ","

    text = ""

    For i = 0 To arrayText.Length Step 1
        text = arrayText(i) & vbCrLf
        MsgBox(text)
    Next
```

When debugging I get error message array out of bounds, however when I remove the newline character (vbCrLf) it displays my text, word for word in a messagebox (which I am using for debugging) and at the end of the loop it kicks out with same error message.

What am I doing wrong here, any improvement suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though walther answer is right, i suggest you to use a `List(Of String)` and a [For Each...Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) loop.

A list is more "modern" and most of the times it is preferred over an array in vb.net. You can use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `vbCrLf`. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but I dont think that using a `MsgBox` is the optimal way to present the seperated words. Here is a simple example of what I think you should do :

```
' Hold the text from the text box.
Dim FullText As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim SeperatedWords As New List(Of String)
' ToList function converts the array to a list.
SeperatedWords = FullText.Split(",").ToList
' Reset the text for re-presentation.
FullText = ""
' Goes through all the seperated words and assign them to FullText with a new line.
For Each Word As String In SeperatedWords
    FullText = FullText & Word & Environment.NewLine
Next
' Present the new list in the text box.
TextBox1.Text = FullText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 0 To arrayText.Length - 1 Step 1
```

Last element has index of `length of array - 1`.

Comment: thank yo so much walter, am I using the correct procedure to add each word on new line?